# Find encrypted and non-specific text in file and replace

Tags: bash, hash, replace, sed

I want to change password for Transmission daemon by editing settings.json file so I'm using **sed** to do that but its not working.

```
sudo sed -i 's/"rpc-password": "{8554bacab8e25167fdb03572871b3e28c557d134LzBdn6ZI.",/"rpc-password": "transmission",/' /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

I want to change this non-specific text that changes when some install script is used

> change "encripted-text" to "password"

Thanks for any help.

PS: this file auto encrypts rpc-password so I just want to validate my new password.

Comment: explain "not working"

Comment: "sed" dont replace text

Comment: Are you trying to encoding that encripted-text, or just replace it with already decrypted one?

Comment: @Marek Nowaczyk replace encrypted text to some password and when the file is saved automatically it will encode again but with my password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
sudo sed -i "s/\"rpc-password\": \"{.*\",/\"rpc-password\": \"transmission\",/g" /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo sed -r -i -e 's/"rpc-password":[ \t]*"\{[^}]+\}",/"rpc-password": "transmission",/' /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Comment: Didn't worked, text won't replace even if stopping transmission-daemon service and start again

Comment: Can you copy config file locally, and check what is done wrong? It's good to know if this is file managing issue or sed expression error.

Comment: I checked file before and after run your script aswell stopping starting daemon, checked in login screen accessing in my browser too

Comment: Can you launch that script in terminal window, what' is on output of it?

Comment: Nothing appears after run that

Comment: Maybe there are tabs instead of spaces, check the script again please.

Comment: Can you copy/paste line with password from original config?

Comment: Ok, I'll check it when go home.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't said file JSON? If so then consider using `jq`:

```
jq '."rpc-password" = "transmission"' \
  /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json \
  > /tmp/trans-set-$$.json && mv /tmp/trans-set-$$.json \
    /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```